# How to get the bound of the param of a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

what I want to do is to write a function get the bound of the input of a function

```
import Data.Int
import Data.Typeable
import Prelude

class (Bounded a, Enum a) => Finite a
instance Finite Int8 where

func::Int8->Int8
func x = x

getMaxParam::(Finite a, Eq b)=>(a->b)->a
getMaxParam f = maxBound $ typeOf a

a = getMaxParam fun
```

But obviously the code do not work. There are limited source online.  I don't know how to deal with the class info. Can anyone help ?

Comment: (This is unrelated to your problem; it is just a code-review style comment.) I don't think that `getMaxParam` is going to be very useful for you. I suspect from your `Eq` constraint that the reason you want it is because you want to write something like `map fun [getMinParam fun .. getMaxParam fun]`. But it's much simpler to use the `Bounded` instance directly, as in `map fun [minBound .. maxBound]`! I suspect that *all* of your uses of `getMaxParam` in the chunk of code you actually want to write (as opposed to the minimized version you're showing us here) can be done with `maxBound` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`typeOf a` doesn't make any sense here, it's the wrong way around: `typeOf` takes a value of some type, and gives you the type of it. (Well, that's actually not possible because types don't exist as runtime values, but `TypeRep` is a *runtime representation* of the type.) But

1. You don't *have* a value of type `a`. The `a` variable is in the type-level language, so you can't mention it in a value-level expression; and it is, well, *the type itself*, not some value of that type.
2. No runtime representation of anything is needed, because the types are perfectly known at *compile* time and the compiler can resolve everything without any such tricks. In fact, it can do it pretty much without any help *at all*: `maxBound` isn't even a function, just a polymorphic value. It doesn't need any arguments, just a context in which the result is given, which it is here.

Thus it's extremely simple: you don't even *need* the function!

```
getMaxParam ::  Finite a => (a->b) -> a
getMaxParam _ = maxBound
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a step back, and look at the type of `maxBound`:

```
maxBound :: Bounded a => a
```

`maxBound` just **is** a value of type `a`, not a function you call on anything to produce one.

To tell it what type you want the maximum bound of, you don't pass it the type you want as a parameter, you simply write `maxBound` where you want the value. `maxBound` is `127` if you write it where you want an `Int8`, or it's `True` if you write it where you want a `Bool`, etc. The compiler knows the type of every single expression and sub-expression in your code<sup>1</sup>, so it **already knows** which type you're trying to get the maximum bound of, you don't need to pass anything to tell it.

This is how type classes work in general, even things like `succ :: Enum a => a -> a` which are functions receiving a value of the type which is an instance of the class. `succ` is **not** a single magic function that can take values of multiple types, which sees what type it receives and then decides what to do. Rather there are many different simple functions that `succ` could be (one for each instance of `Enum`) and the compiler decides which one to use because it knows what type of *function* is needed where `succ` was written<sup>2</sup>. And the compiler decides what function `succ` is **before** it is passed any input, so the input doesn't determine which function is called<sup>3</sup>.

This is a key confusion a lot of people have learning Haskell after learning how classes work in object-oriented languages. The methods of an OO class are all tied to the objects of that class, so you can usually only get access to them by calling the methods on such an object. The methods of a Haskell type class are tied to the type, and do not need to be called on a value of that type (or on anything at all, in cases like `maxBound`).

So, coming back to the OP's specific problem. How do we fill in the blank here:

```
getMaxParam::(Finite a, Eq b)=>(a->b)->a
getMaxParam f = _
```

Well, the compiler already knows what the **type** of that blank is (and if you try to compile that it'll tell you). It's the `a` from the type declaration above.  So we can just write `maxBound` and it'll pick the right value for us, nothing else required!

```
getMaxParam::(Finite a, Eq b)=>(a->b)->a
getMaxParam _ = maxBound
```

(Since we aren't using `f` I replaced it with `_`, which signals to the compiler that we weren't intending to use it; with some settings it'll emit warning messages about unused parameters otherwise).

Now note that in `a = getMaxParam fun` the only purpose `fun` is serving is to cause type inference to decide what type this usage of `getMaxParam` has, which in turn determines that type (and value) the `maxBound` inside it has. If we had a type signature for `a`:

```
a :: Int8
a = getMaxParam fun
```

Then we don't really need `getMaxParam` at all. Since we can just write:

```
a :: Int8
a = maxBound
```

To get the `maxBound` of `Int8` without reference to `fun`. Whether you still *want* to use `getMaxParam` is up to you. When writing lots of polymorphic code it often *is* useful to have functions like `getMaxParam` which don't really "do anything", but link the types of things in useful ways. But in a bigger context where you're actually doing something with the values (say, enumerating all the possible inputs to the function and then applying the function to each of them) you probably don't need `getMaxParam`; just writing `maxBound` instead of `getMaxParam fun` will likely work. The reason is that if you end up passing `maxBound` to `fun` then it's *already* constrained to be of same type as `fun`'s input parameter (you'll get a type error if that doesn't work). You don't need to write a function that analyses `fun` to do that, because that analysis is built into the compiler.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some of the types it knows because you told it by writing type declarations. For the rest it figures out the only possible type at each position; if it can't do that you'll get type errors.

---

<sup>2</sup> The story I've told here is a little over-simplified, because you can also use class methods in positions where the type expected is not a single concrete type but a polymorphic type (where an appropriate class constraint is available). For example:

```
penultimate :: (Num a, Bounded a) => a
penultimate = maxBound - 1
```

Here there's no single value the compiler can use for `maxBound`, rather the caller of `penultimate` will decide (by deciding what type it needs).

In such cases, ultimately there will be *some* place (or places) where the compiler can see a particular concrete type it needs for `maxBound`, but that decision will have to be passed around to get to `penultimate` to tell it what value to use for `maxBound`. That's what the constraints (the stuff left of the `=>` in a type) represent; decisions about type class instances that the compiler will have to pass around.

I recommend you don't think too hard about this yet if you're just beginning. Just remember: class methods are chosen by the compiler based on the type inferred, not based on any inputs they receive.

---

<sup>3</sup> Of course, type inference looks at everything you've written to decide what type each expression must be. So sometimes it's possible that the instance chosen for a class member function *is* in fact determined by the input. But it's the **type** of the input that matters, at compile time; not the **value** of the input at runtime, nor its runtime type.